# Using Universal Windows Platform (Windows 10) controls in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, win-universal-app

Hopefully a simple question; I seem to recall seeing somebody at one of the recent Microsoft conferences say that some of the UWP application functionality was to be made available within WPF/Desktop. Unfortunately, I can no longer find (or remember) which of the many videos this was from (though it was probably Build or similar on Channel9).

Is it therefore possible to use UWP controls within a WPF application? Basically I want the look and feel of an "app", including some of the new controls (RelativePanel, SplitPanel) and the themed buttons etc., but I need the power of the full desktop - such as access to the full file system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the different Bridges to port apps to Windows 10 from for instance, IOS, Android, Web, Win32, etc. and still take advantage of Windows 10 features and APIs.  Specifically, I think you are talking about the Bridge to bring in Win32 apps.  You can find the bridges listed here.

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/bridges

•"Project Centennial": This toolkit will enable desktop developers to package and publish their existing .NET and Win32-based Windows applications to the Windows Store. Developers can also use Centennial to call common UWP APIs and services."